# gcc can't find define in header

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm using a header called `lib.h` to organize my source code. The header is like:

```
#define TOT_REP 10
#define TOT_PAT 10
#define TIME_REP 15
```

The source file include the header, but when i compile with gcc i'm getting this:

```
error: ‘TIME_REP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

So i tried to compile with `gcc -E -dM` and i got something like this:

```
...
#define SIGUSR2 12
#define TIME_REP 15
#define ____mbstate_t_defined 1
#define __SIGRTMIN 32
...
```

I also tried with `gcc -E`  and in the outuput i found that  the macro is properly replaced with its value.

What can I do to solve this?

EDIT: The code where TIME_REP is used is this:

```
while((!ending|| *(shmAddress+0)!=0)&& quitSignal==0){

      totFolder=0;
      buf=(char*)calloc(2,sizeof(char));
      patientString=(char*)calloc(2,sizeof(char));

      sleep(TIME_REP); 
      while(read(fd,buf,sizeof(char))>0){
         /*read from a file and get some data*/
      }
   }
```

EDIT 2: I tried to rename the lib.h and it seems to work now but i just can't understand why if with gcc -E -Dm  found the macro then i can't compile the code.

Anyway to answer to Woodrow Barlow:

i have the lib.h and a rep.c the rep.c include the lib.h and other headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ReaderWriter.h"
#include "lib.h"
```

To compile I use `gcc rep.c -o rep -Wall -pedantic`

Comment: Can you show us the code where you're using `TIME_REP`?

Comment: show usage where it causes error.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `lib.h` is a common name,, might be worth a quick try to rename it (and the `#define` guard if you have one) to something more unique just in case there are conflicts with some other `lib.h`

Comment: you'll need to tell us what commands you are using to compile the program and where the files are in relation to each other.

Comment: hmmm... still don't think there's enough here. `typedef/#include/#define` errors can be hard to track down. I think this is one of those problems where we need to see everything. Full contents of all your personal header and source files, as well as the directory structure where they are located (I assume all source and headers are in the same directory based on how you're including them?). I think you already have, but verify `TIME_REP` isn't defined twice somewhere, and change it's name to something unique to make sure it isn't defined in one of your `#include`s that you don't own.

Comment: furthermore, these types of errors may not even manifest themselves as the compiler error suggests. You said yourself the preprocessor correctly substituted in the right value. It could be an unrelated error somewhere further up and for some reason it's puking on `TIME_REP`.